# Why does batch file using WinRAR to archive a folder taking much longer to finish than expected?

Tags: cmd, task, batch-file, scheduler, winrar

I have this script which moves all my folders and files from my `c:\projects` directory into a RAR archive in `c:\backup`.

```
for /f "delims==" %%D in ('DIR C:\projects /A /B /S') do (
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.EXE" m -r "c:\backup\projects.rar" "%%D"
)
```

I have also tried the below script which uses the same source `c:\projects`, but creates a separate archive for each folder in `c:\projects` in `c:\backup`.

```
FOR /F "DELIMS==" %%D in ('DIR C:\projects /AD /B') DO (
    "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.EXE" m -r "C:\Backup\%%D.rar" "%%D"
)
```

This second script only takes two hours to run while my first script takes over 24 hours to run.

Is there any way to make my first script faster?

Shouldn't my first script be faster at all?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your "c:\backup\projects.rar" archive is a solid archive, which means that it needs to be re-packed entirely each time you add something to it.
Try changing it to non-solid archive and I think you should see improvement.

The second thing you could try is to do a single call to WinRar with file-list (or even a mask) of what folders to add instead of calling it independently for each folder.

Comment: how do i change it to a non-solid archive?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can change existing archive. But you definitely can create a new one. It is controlled by the "Create solid archive" option or by -S (enable solid) / -S- (disable solid) command line switches.